# sockets - android client to c# server connect

Tags: c#, java, android, eclipse, sockets

I try to connect from android to c# - server . My computer ip adress is : "10.100.102.7" ;
I tested android Client and Server applications and they work good , the problem start when i try to connect from android to C# - server

C# :

```
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.100.102.7"), 6000);/
listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
listener.Listen(100);
Receiver = listener.Accept();
```

Java :

```
private Socket Sender_Socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.100.102.7";

class Connect_To_Server implements Runnable
 {
  @Override
  public void run()
   {
    try
     {
      InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
      Sender_Socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
     }
    catch (UnknownHostException e1)
     {
      e1.printStackTrace();
     }
    catch (IOException e1)
     {
      e1.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }
```

In C# - it stops on "Receiver = listener.Accept();"
In java(android) - it stops on "Sender_Socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);"
It should be problem in the java socket function - there is needed another function to connect to C# - server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off the firewall and now they can to connect ;

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually send something, all you have done in the Java class is retrieved the InetAddress and opened a socket?

You need to actually do something like send a packet...

Start by reading this :

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

Then work your way through some of these examples: 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Also you should make sure you add another (this time generic) error catcher, as those exceptions you handle are not the only two that could happen when playing with sockets/connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Connected");
listener.Send(byData);
waitForData(listener);


void waitForData(SocketState state)
    {
        try
        {
            state.Socket.BeginReceive(state.DataBuffer, 0, state.DataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(readDataCallback), state);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            //Socket has been closed  
            //Close/dispose of socket
        }
    }

    public void readDataCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        SocketState state = (SocketState)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            // Read data from the client socket.
            int iRx = state.Socket.EndReceive(ar);

            //Handle Data....

            waitForData(state);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            //Socket has been closed  
            //Close/dispose of socket
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            //Socket exception
            //Close/dispose of socket
        }
    }
```

am good in C# only